# git rev-list with a gitrevision range argument on circleci build not working

Tags: git, circleci-2.0

For [this repro repo](https://github.com/ozimos/circleci-git-test.git) 
in a CircleCI pipeline build job
`git rev-list --count develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1`
 returns 0.

Ditto for
`git rev-list --count develop..HEAD`.

Also `git rev-list develop..HEAD` does nothing

[build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJU8j.png)

All the git commands above produce a different result when run locally.
`git rev-list --count HEAD` returns the same non zero value for both local and CircleCI runs.
It appears `git rev-list` fails on CircleCI whenever a [gitrevision range](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_revision_range_summary) argument is supplied
Am I doing something wrong? How do I get `git rev-list` to work with a gitrevision range?

config.yml

```
version: 2.1

executors:
    base:
        docker:
            - image: cimg/base:2020.01

jobs:
    build:
        executor: base
        steps:
        - checkout
        - run:
            name: Test git in bash script
            command: chmod +x .circleci/circle_test.sh && .circleci/circle_test.sh
        - run:
            name: Test git in circleci command
            environment:
                PACKAGE_PATH: "./packages"       
            command: |
                echo -e $(git rev-list -1 develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1 -- ${PACKAGE_PATH#./} | cat)
                echo -e $(git rev-list -1 develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1 | cat)
                echo -e $(git rev-list develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1 | cat)
                git rev-list --count develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1
                git rev-list --count HEAD

workflows:
    version: 2
    ci:
        jobs:
        - build
```

.circleci/circle_test.sh

```sh
PACKAGE_PATH="./packages" 

LATEST_PACKAGE_COMMIT_SINCE_DEVELOP=$(git rev-list -1 develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1 -- ${PACKAGE_PATH#./})

LATEST_COMMIT_SINCE_DEVELOP=$(git rev-list -1 develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1)

COMMITS_SINCE_DEVELOP=$(git rev-list develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1)

COMMITS_COUNT_SINCE_DEVELOP=$(git rev-list --count develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1)

COMMITS_COUNT=$(git rev-list --count HEAD)

echo -e "\e[36m  first changed commit in package since develop $LATEST_PACKAGE_COMMIT_SINCE_DEVELOP \e[0m"

echo -e "\e[36m  first changed commit since develop $LATEST_COMMIT_SINCE_DEVELOP \e[0m"

echo -e "\e[36m  commits since develop $COMMITS_SINCE_DEVELOP \e[0m"

echo -e "\e[36m  commits count since develop $COMMITS_COUNT_SINCE_DEVELOP \e[0m"

echo -e "\e[36m  commits count $COMMITS_COUNT \e[0m"

echo -e "\e[36m  this commit $CIRCLE_SHA1 \e[0m"
```

Comment: I have never used or set up CircleCI but `git-shallow-clone` sounds like the problem: a shallow clone is one that deliberately omits most commits. You can't count commits you don't have. To count commits, don't use shallow clones.

Comment: @torek I have changed the circleci config to use the normal circleci checkout and updated the post to reflect this. I am still getting the same results as before

Comment: OK - the problem is perhaps now reduced to something specific to CircleCI itself ... not having used it, I don't know! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CircleCI use the full commit sha1 instead of branch names
For example, the sha1 for the develop branch using bash
`DEVELOP_SHA1=$(git rev-parse origin/develop)`

Then `LATEST_COMMIT_SINCE_DEVELOP=$(git rev-list -1 develop..$CIRCLE_SHA1)` should be written as `LATEST_COMMIT_SINCE_DEVELOP=$(git rev-list -1 $DEVELOP_SHA1..$CIRCLE_SHA1)`